# How to add entity extension in Shopware 6 App?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

I want to query the categories of the product in the product listing of a Shopware app, so that I can query the customFields of all categories. Is this even possible with an app?

I have already tried via a navigation-page-loaded. And when I override the box-standard.html.twig and access the product, I can't access the categories there.

For each product i want the categories extensions

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `categories` association is not loaded for products in the listing you have to fetch the `categories` using an app script.

As already noted, add the script to the `navigation-page-loaded` hook, i.e. in `Resources/scripts/navigation-page-loaded/category-loader.twig`:

```
{% set products = [] %}

{% if hook.page.cmsPage.type === 'product_list' %}
    {% foreach hook.page.cmsPage.sections as section %}
        {% foreach section.blocks as sectionBlock %}
            {% if sectionBlock.type !== 'product-listing' %}
                {% continue %}
            {% endif %}

            {% foreach sectionBlock.slots as slot %}
                {% if slot.type !== 'product-listing' %}
                    {% continue %}
                {% endif %}

                {% foreach slot.data.listing.entities as product %}
                    {% set products = products|merge([product]) %}
                {% endforeach %}
            {% endforeach %}
        {% endforeach %}
    {% endforeach %}
{% endif %}

{% set categoryIds = products|reduce((carry, v) => carry|merge(v.categoryIds), []) %}
{% if categoryIds %}
    {% set categories = services.repository.search('category', {'ids': categoryIds}) %}

    {% foreach products as product %}
        {% do product.addArrayExtension('myCategories', {
            'categories': categories.entities.getList(product.categoryIds),
        }) %}
    {% endforeach %}
{% endif %}
```

Where we first extract all the products, than load the categories of all products at once, and than assign the categories back to the products.

Note that for reading the category entity you need the correct permission, i.e. in the `manifest.xml` add:

```xml
<permissions>
    <read>category</read>
    <read>category_translation</read>
</permissions>
```

Now you should be able to access in the `box-standard.html.twig` template the categories using `product.extensions.myCategories.categories`.

Comment: This works thanks! But it its possible to get the whole category tree into this? Only the last category is considered here?

Comment: You mean that also all parent categories are loaded? Or do you just need the values needed in the breadcrumb? If it is the later, you can access them through [`category.getPlainBreadcrumb()`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Core/Content/Category/CategoryEntity.php#L593). If you need more, I would probably load the categories defined in the breadcrumb, in as similar way as described in the answer. Depends a bit what exactly you need.

Comment: My solution is: product.categoryTree but thanks for your answer!

Comment: This script is not working, if local filters are applied. Cause Shopware does not make a whole site reload.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your issue correctly, you are trying to access a product's category's custom fields in some piece of storefront logic (like a Twig template).

The way I see it, you would have to add [a script](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-scripts#example-script-loading-media-entities) that would enable you to query the repository for the categories and their custom fields. The issue is, a `SalesChannelProductEntity` will not contain the information about all its categories (only the `SeoCategory`), so you might need to first query the `product_category` repository.

Generally, it is going to be complicated but it should be doable.

Comment: Yeah, but in which script i should do this?

Comment: You'd probably have to go with one of the `-page-loaded` hooks from [here](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/app-reference/script-reference/script-hooks-reference). There is no `listing-page-loaded` but you should have some success with `cms-page-loaded` or in some cases `landing-page-loaded`.